# Do these Latin phrases make sense?

Tags: translation-check, syntax

So I am working on a phrase I want to put on a piece of apparel I am making. The phrase in English has two lines. In English, the lines are as follows:

"**The Church must always be reformed**" and

"**By the guidance of the Holy Spirit and the authority of the Bible**"

How I have the lines translated into Latin right now respectively as:

"**Ecclesia semper reformanda**" and

"**Spiritus Sancti ductu et auctoritate Bibliorum**"

Can someone look them over and tell me if that is right and if there are any issues with the grammar or syntax? FYI, I am very much a beginner when it comes to Latin.

Comment: I’m a mere beginner in Latin, but I think there’s something missing in each sentence. The first one doesn’t seem to have translated the part “must,” whereas the second one seems to be missing “by the.” I think the second one should be “ Spiritus Sancti…” But that’s only my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful comment. I am going to wait for some more feedback before making a decision. But I appreciate your insight nonetheless.

Comment: Wise course of action, considering I’m just a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your grammar and syntax are right.

Especially your first line, *Ecclesia semper reformanda*. This is a classic motto, and it means exactly what you say.

Your second line, *Spiritus Sancti ductu et auctoritate Bibliorum* is fine as well. *Auctoritas* is obviously cognate with "authority", but in Latin I think it maybe means something more like the personal influence of one person on another. You might be able to find another word that is, arguably, a better fit for the authority of the Bible.

A couple of alternatives, depending on your aims:

Matthew 7:29 uses uses *potestas* as in *Erat enim docens eos sicut potestatem habens, et non sicut scribae* for "he taught them with authority, and not like the scribes".

You could object to the vagueness of *potestas*, which can mean any kind of power or capability, and not just "authority". Such vagueness could be a feature in certain contexts, and a bug in others. A Latin word meaning "teaching authority" is *magisterium*, and it might make a good fit for your purposes.

The usual word for legal authority is *imperium*. I'm not sure that's exactly what you're trying to say here, though.

If you decide to go with *potestas*, *magisterium*, or *imperium*, be sure to put them in the ablative like you've already done with *auctoritate*: *potestate*, or *magisterio*, or *imperio*.

Comment: Thanks a TON for your input and informative answer. After looking at the alternative words you suggested I think what best fits what I am going for is "Magisterio" so after making the edit the final phasing would come out to "Spiritus Sancti ductu et magisterio Bibliorum". I really appreciate the assistance.